# How to check what network your wallet is on, ReactJs

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, solana-cli

I am using @solana/wallet-adapter-react
How can I check what network I am on? because I want to show an alert to users that they are on devnet and should switch to mainnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, the "standard" wallet doesn't report any state back to the adapter except the public key and the functions to send transactions.

Note that you can't even read the SOL balance from the wallet, even though phantom clearly has that info in the extension. You have to send a getBalance() request to the RPC.

This is annoying because if you send a tx and the user is on the wrong network, they get a very generic failure error about too long to approve the tx (at least on Phantom). It's also neat because you can read a wallet's balance on some network even if they are connected to another network.

Comment: wow
So how do you suggest I go about my situation?
Just hope that the user discovers he's on devnet and switches to mainnet?

Comment: You can send a dummy "test" tx and see if it errors, but that's not a great solution because the user still has to sign it. Tbh this is rarely an issue because normal users do not generally switch to devnet. The setting to switch to devnet is hidden under "developer settings" in most wallets.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the network you are currently on by using `WalletAdapterNetwork`

**example**

```
export const Wallet: FC = () => {
    // The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

    // You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
    const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

    ...
};
```

Taken from https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md

Comment: Have you tested this code? it always connects to same wallet regardless you are on testnet, devmet or main-beta

Comment: The cluster used for website != cluster used in your wallet.

The website will use the assigned cluster. But the wallet might show a different cluster. Most Solana wallets implement a feature to change the cluster you want to view your balances for.

Comment: I know how to set the network
What I want to do is check what network the user's wallet is set to
I noticed on opensea that an alert dialog is shown at the top of the page when I am on devnet. So I want to achieve that same thing here with solana wallets

Comment: "The cluster used for website != cluster used in your wallet."... Oh so does this mean the user doesn't need to change the network to devnet? and as long I set the cluset to mainnet, he's gonna get charged from mainnet balance?

Comment: @NooblantisDistrict even though you change the cluster in react, from devnet to mainnet-beta, the connected wallet is still the same on the phantom. I do not understand what is going on.